# how do i set different minimumInteritemSpacing for same section?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewlayout

**Swift 4, Xcode 9.2**
Hello,
i want to make `UICellectionView`'s layout like bellow,

[image]
how can i achive this?

Comment: Please don't use italic for a whole paragraph unless it conveys a meaning.

Comment: It's not possible directly, you should add padding inside the cells themselves. (I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find a dupe.)

Comment: @the4kman i really tried to find before i asked.. and YES, i know this is not possible directly that's why i asked for help. :D

Comment: A possible solution for this is declaring a variable inside your cell and setting that as a constraint's constant if you're using Auto Layout (or using that variable directly if you lay out the cell's subviews manually). You should pass the value for that variable in `cellForRowAt:`.